# Insert a String Value with Semicolon Causes Error

Tags: sql, syntax, syntax-error

How can I escape a semicolon in a string for insert into an SQL database table?

Example:

```
Insert Into items(Description)
Values('Anti Surge T; LBC Slow Blow 6.3 x 32mm 7A / 250V');
```

Comment: in which mysql version??

Comment: SQL or MYSQL??? please tag specific

Comment: @diEcho - Sorry, I was thinking it might be the same for both... MySQL version is 5.1.

Comment: I am having this problem also, it seems the sql engine is parsing all the semi colons as end of statement delimiters. I think you need to run a command to change this behaviour but I didn't find the command yet.

Answer (score 1):

semicolon in a string should not cause any problem, still enclose the string in single quotes in insert statement.

Comment: Thanks... I think I should look into how my statement is parsed in my code then

Comment: yaah.. the best way ever.  Please have a look at the DataType that the column can store...